# Cannot get Wordpress REST API to work online but it works on my local installation

Tags: php, node.js, wordpress, .htaccess, rest

so I'm working on this website, the backend is Node.js and I need to use the Wordpress REST API to create users in a blog, so the users of my website have access to it, I built a code that does this and it works perfectly on my local installation of Wordpress, but for the life of me I cannot get it to work on the actual blog I need to point to, here's the snippet of the code that makes the request:

```
export function generateWPUser(req, res){
var postData = querystring.stringify({
    username: req.body.name,
    password: '12345',
    email: req.body.email
  });

var options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "hostname": "localhost",
  "path": "/wp-json/wp/v2/users",
  "data": {
    "username":req.body.name,
    "password":"12345",
    "email":req.body.email
  },
  "headers": {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData),
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + newBuffer("user:password").toString('base64')
  }
};

var requ = http.request(options, function (resu) {
  var chunks = [];

  resu.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  resu.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });
});
requ.write(postData);
requ.end();
}
```

Other details:

- I'm using "Basic Auth", I know it's not really recommended for a production enviroment and I do plan to change to OAuth or another method but for the time being I really need this running with this auth
- I already enabled CORS on my actual website
- I added this to my .htaccess:

> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*) RewriteRule ^(.*)
>
> [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

I don't know what else to try here, I'd appreciate any help, if you think I missed any details or have questions for me, please do tell me, I'm not used to post it here so I have a little trouble explaining myself

Answer (score 0):

1. Please consider checking logs from both your node.js and wordpress
   host. They will tell you what went wrong.
2. Based on your code, you didn't put in your username:password
   variable into the header `'Authorization': 'Basic ' +
   newBuffer("user:password").toString('base64')`
3. Please consider using Application Passwords or Web Tokens for your node.js
   authentication
   https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#authentication-plugins

> Note that this plugin requires sending your username and password with
>   every request, and should only be used for development and testing
>   i.e. not in a production environment.

4. To save your time and effort, please considering using [node-wpapi](https://github.com/WP-API/node-wpapi) to achieve your goal.

Comment: I did put the password, It's right below the content-length, it's not getting recognized by the server somehow, I'll look into web tokens again, I actually had tried them already and I get the same response, the problem is that my WP server is not recognizing the auth header, and thanks for the library, I'll have a look.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't look like node-wpapi works to create users, I took a quick look to the docs and it seems you canly use the me() function for users, oh well, I'll have to keep on searching.

Comment: @RamiroGarcilazo What is the exact message from your WP server?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I ended up doing what I needed to do quick and dirty with a PHP script, but I know that's not really safe, so I would like to get the official API working for me, the exact message I get is "rest_cannot_create" along with "sorry you are not allowed to create new users"

Comment: Intreasting discussion found at here https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2252